# Link to xenforo Profile from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Please tell me how to link to xenforo forum user profile from wordpress??
For example:
from wordpress:

```
<a href="http:/mysite.com/forum/members/author">user</a>
```

Wordpress uses:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($post->post_author) ?>">User name</a>
```

**My forum is on subdomain relative path (../forum) and i use:
XenScripts WordPress to XenForo Bridge.**
Thank you

Comment: Inspect [all the user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to see if Xen is there. Also, are the usernames the same?

Comment: Usernames are same...because all login and registration controled by xenfor, But i can't findout how to link to user ID???

Comment: Please add **more details** to your Question. I don't have any idea what Xen is, but can help in WP side. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and thank you for replay: XENFORO it's forum and here is the link to plugin i use as bridge between xenforo and wordpress:
http://xenscripts.com/
Thank you

Comment: I won't analyse the bridge, I count with you doing the research... Or waiting until someone who knows XenForo to show up...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/community/members/'. strtolower($XF->visitor->get('username')) . '.' . $XF->visitor->get('user_id') .'">'.$current_user->display_name.'</a>
```

Change the href to your XF installation.

Comment: Not working....i want to link post author to his profile, Not logged in user....PLEASE...any idea. Thank you